# Azure SQL database table - archiving to different Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to move all data from one Azure SQL Server to different Azure SQL Server which more than 90 days old, and after moving need to delete moved data from first Azure SQL Server.

I want to run these steps on daily basis.

I am new to Azure and able to do same with Azure Data Factory. Can you please suggest any other best suited approach?

Comment: 1. Why do you want to archive data? 2. What issue are you having with ADF? ADF is probably the best tool for this. There are other much more convoluted methods like BCP, Powershell in Runbooks, .Net in Azure Functions but they offer no benefit.

Comment: 1. we need to archieve data due to two reason a.) we are getting arround 3 million record daily and we have 90% heat for first 3 month data only  b) we have different screen in UX to display data from 3 month to 1 year, hence building diffrent microservices.  2. My team is not getting approved to use Data factory

Comment: So if you have a performance issue around a high data volume, there are other more transparent ways to solve it, such as adding indexes or implementing partitioning. This can improve performance without requiring complex archiving logic. If you are not allowed to use data factory, what are you allowed to use? Code running on a VM? Azure Functions? Azure Automation? Why aren't you allowed to use ADF? It seems like a case of "pointy haired boss" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss

Comment: You can use table partitioning to move data between tables as it ages.  So, if you are able/willing to use the same DB for each microservice, this might get you separation enough to do what you appear to be trying to do.

Comment: Is it 1 table, or many tables with dependencies (foreign keys) between tables?

Comment: its multiple table with dependencies(foreign keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using the best approach.

Azure Data Factory is an easy to use when it comes to extract and copy the data between the services. It also provide scheduling the triggers, i.e., triggering the copy pipeline after specific interval of time or any event. Refer [Create a trigger that runs a pipeline on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory).

If the volume of data is large, you can re-configure the Integration Runtime (IR) resources (Compute type and Core count) to overcome the performance issue, if required. Refer below image.

[image]